# My web driver sampler for jmeter wont open

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriver, jmeter-plugins

My jmeter webdriver sampler wont open. Here is the error :

```
2019-07-09 18:55:00,153 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences.checkPreference(Preferences.java:225) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences.setPreference(Preferences.java:155) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences.setPreference(Preferences.java:126) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences.readDefaultPreferences(Preferences.java:105) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences.<init>(Preferences.java:66) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:82) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:72) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:61) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createProfile(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:39) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:98) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:22) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:762) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) ~[jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) ~[jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:730) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:718) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
2019-07-09 18:55:00,154 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-07-09 18:55:00,154 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your guava version is old and not compatible, you need to update it in JMeter lib folder

Close JMeter to change versions,

[Download](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/23.0) guava-23.0.jar and put it in JMeter lib folder

Remove/Change extension of old guava-19.0.0.jar from lib folder